# A question on accumulation points

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Suppose $S$ is a **closed**, **countable**, subset of $\mathbb{C}$. For any $n$, define $S_n:=S_{n-1}\backslash B_{n-1}$, where $B_{n-1}$ is the set of isolated points of $S_{n-1}$ (as usual, $S_0:=S$). Is it possible that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $S_n\neq\emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Cantor-Bendixson rang of a countable closed set is defined as the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $S_\alpha = \emptyset$, where your definition is extended to the limit cases by $S_\gamma = \bigcap_{\beta < \gamma}$ for limit ordinals $\gamma$.

For compact sets, any countable successor ordinal occurs as the Cantor-Bendixson rank; for arbitrary closed sets any countable ordinal will.

Comment: Do you know a concrete example when the Cantor-Bendixon index is at least $\omega$ (which, if I understand you corectly, would be a concrete answer to my question).

Comment: If you do have compact examples for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, just take their disjoint union. To get the examples for finite $n$, notice that any isolated point has a small isolating ball around it, and you can place a sequence in there converging to the point. Doing that for all isolated points then gives you the $+1$ on the Cantor-Bendixson rank.